# Update Javascript Array and stringify again

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

Sooo i have this array

```
var items = ["shovel", "sword", "rope", "gun"];
```

i stringify it and place in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
```

Then i call this function that replaces the index value of the passed variable with an empty string. This is so I can check whether or not a value at a specific array index is available. The value is removed but its index remains to be checked later.

```
function removeItem(itm) {
    var itemArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));   //old array
    var index = itemArray.indexOf(itm);
    if (index > -1) {
        itemArray[index]="";  //edited new array
        localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(itemArray)); //does not store
    }
}
```

However the newly edited array will not go back into localStorage

Comment: I would abstract out the localStorage parts into their own service/class so that it is consistent. Then in you removeItem function use this class to get the array, modify it and send it back. Just as an initial improvement. So following S of SOLID

Comment: [Your code appears to work just fine.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/XJddMN)

Comment: hey your code is working fine .  i checked  it many times. might be another problem.  please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/tto685z4/

```
var items = ["shovel", "sword", "rope", "gun"];

localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));

function removeItem(itm) {
    var itemArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));   //old array
    var index = itemArray.indexOf(itm);
    if (index > -1) {
        itemArray[index]="";  //edited new array
        localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(itemArray)); //does not store
    }
}

removeItem('rope');

alert(localStorage.getItem('items'));
```

Returns `["shovel", "sword", "", "gun"]`

You must have been trying to remove a non-existing item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete element at all, just make some changes:

```
itemArray[index]="";
```

change to:

```
itemArray = itemArray.splice(index, 1) and you will not see this element again
```